# Postgresql query to get users who have a few attributes within 24 hours of account creation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime

I'm trying to write a SQL query for a Rails app to get the number of users who have followed three users, followed three tags, and left a note, all within 24 hours of creating their account.

The model structure is:

- Users model have an ID and `created_at` column, and a user `has_many` follows and comments.
- Follows model has a `follower_id` that matches a user's id and a `follower_type`, which is either `"User"` or `"Tag"`, as well as a `created_at`.
- Comment model has a `user_id` that matches a user's id and a `created_at`.

I haven't gotten very far since my SQL skills are subpar. Closest (which again is still very far) I got was something like this:

```
 select count(*)
 from users
 where created_at >= 
 (select follows.created_at 
  from follows 
  where follows.follower_id = users.id);
```

Comment: `select follows.created_at 
  from follows 
  where follows.follower_id = users.id` this will return array of created_at and how will it be compared? i m not sure what are you asking. can you explain more

Comment: Yeah, that's the part that I didn't get to. The query I gave is just the closest query I got, and was stuck on a few parts.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing this in raw SQL, instead of using ActiveRecord?

Comment: Eventually I'm going to graph this count out per day, and my data dashboard/visualization tool takes raw SQL as opposed to ActiveRecord. Happy to take ActiveRecord answers too though. My only concern is using `.to_sql` will give me the actual `created_at` timestamp as opposed to a flexible variable for Postgres to take in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible ActiveRecord solution. Note that I've only tested variants of this in IRB, and your model may be slightly different to what my assumptions are here. Also, I am no SQL expert so this may not be efficient.

```
User
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN follows as fu on fu.follower_id = users.id AND fu.created_at < (users.created_at + interval '1 day') AND fu.follower_type = 'User'")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN follows as ft on ft.follower_id = users.id AND ft.created_at < (users.created_at + interval '1 day') AND ft.follower_type = 'Tag'")
  .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN comments as c on c.user_id = users.id AND c.created_at < (users.created_at + interval '1 day')")
  .group("users.id")
  .having("COUNT(distinct fu.id)>=3 AND COUNT(distinct ft.id)>=3 AND COUNT(distinct c.id)>=1")
```

You can take a look at the console output to translate it to raw SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is definitely a great start. I think we need to change the less than signs to greater than signs since later times are considered greater than older times (10/31/2017 > 10/29/2017 == true).

Running the query against my data doesn't seem to work though. I get zero entries.

Comment: Are you sure? If a user was created at `10/30/2017 08:00`, user.created_at + 1 day is `10/31/2017 08:00`. If a comment was created at `10/30/2017 12:00`, then we want that comment to be included in the count. So `'10/30/2017 12:00' < '10/31/2017 08:00' == true`, which is what the above is testing for.

Comment: Ah I think you're right. I made a Rails project if you'd like to sandbox, and that way we could have consistent numbers and data.
https://github.com/Zhao-Andy/sql-example-project

Comment: Just cloned - will report back :)

Comment: OK - I just ran the code above and got 49 results back, which is what the README suggests is correct. Take a look at my fork: https://github.com/hicklin-james/sql-example-project - I added a class method to the User model. Try running `User.test_method.length` in your console and see if you get the same. Also note that calling `count` instead of `length` will return a hash due to the `group` call.

Comment: Awesome! I must have mistyped something on my database because I'm getting 98, but I reset my database and re-seeded to get 49. Thanks for all the help! EDIT: Actually, could you tell me what the values of 9 are referring to in the hash?

Comment: Also, I wonder how I'm going to change `.length` `to_sql`. Using SQL `count(*)` still gives me rows.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96147/postgres-count-of-group-by - the second example in the accepted answer works for me when I adapt the output from `User.test_method.count.count`. I ran the raw query and was left with a single row that had the `count_all` column set to 49.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) OVER () AS count_all, users.id AS users_id FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN follows as fu on fu.user_id = users.id AND fu.created_at < (users.created_at + interval '1 day') AND fu.follower_type = 'User' LEFT OUTER JOIN follows as ft on ft.user_id = users.id AND ft.created_at < (users.created_at + interval '1 day') AND ft.follower_type = 'Tag' LEFT OUTER JOIN comments as c on c.user_id = users.id AND c.created_at < (users.created_at + interval '1 day') GROUP BY users.id HAVING (COUNT(distinct fu.id)>=3 AND COUNT(distinct ft.id)>=3 AND COUNT(distinct c.id)>=1) LIMIT 1"`